# Solve $W_0(x)^2 - W_{-1}(x)^2 = c$ for $x<0$ with sufficiently large $c>0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

Suppose we have
$$
W_0(x)^2 - W_{-1}(x)^2 = c
$$
for some constant $c>0$  with $x<0$. Then can we solve for $x$ algebraically? Or at least analytically find bounds for $x$?

Here we can assume $c$ is very large. The equation is from this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236674/maximize-exponential-sum-sum-i-ec-x-i-constrained-to-lvert-x-rvert-1).

Also, we may represent $x$ in other forms; for example, $x \leftarrow e^{-x-1}$ changing the range of $x$ to $0<x$ and then use [bounds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04895.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Since $W_0(x)^2<1$, $W_{-1}(x)^2>1$
and hence $W_0(x)^2-W_{-1}(x)^2<0$
$\forall x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm e},0)$,
there is no solution for $c>0$.